# Subgroups of Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \ldots)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \ldots)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$; it is infinite Galois extension.

Its automorphisms have order $2$, of the form $$
\sigma: \sqrt{-1}\mapsto \epsilon_1\sqrt{-1}, \,\,\,\,
\sqrt{2}\mapsto \epsilon_2\sqrt{2}, \,\,\,\, \ldots (\epsilon_i\in \{1,-1\}).
$$
**Qeustion:**

Does the subgroups $\{1,\sigma\}$ of order $2$ bijectively correspond to subfields $L$ with $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \ldots):L]=2$?

**My answer:** yes.

Given a subgroup $\{1,\sigma\}$ of order $2$ (of Galois group), if we partiton $\{\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5},\ldots\}$ as
$$
\{ \sqrt{c_1}, \sqrt{c_2}, \ldots \} \cup \{ \sqrt{d_1}, \sqrt{d_2}, \ldots \}
$$
such that $\sigma$ fixes $\sqrt{c_i}$ but takes $\sqrt{d_j}$ to $-\sqrt{d_j}$, then $L$ turns out to be
$$
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{c_i}, \sqrt{d_jd_k})_{j<k}.
$$
Further attaching to $L$ any single $\sqrt{d_i}$ covers full field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \ldots)$, so
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \ldots):L]=2
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You showed that for every subgroup of order 2, you obtain a field of index 2. But do you obtain *every* field of index 2?

Comment: If $L'$ is a subfield of index $2$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{2}, \ldots)$ is Galois over $L'$ giving subgroup of order $2$, say $H'$; then fixed field of $H'$ must be $L'$ only!

Comment: Now I am okay with it